# type="password" changes to type="text" when field is selected

Tags: html

I have a login form on http://portal.codeclimb.com

If you visit the page and inspect the element of the input field for the password you can see that when the field is selected that type="password" is changed to type="text" which then results in the password being shown when typing in any content. When you un select the field type="text" will convert back to type="password" and will then hide the password.

Any idea on what may be causing this problem?

Comment: Javascript. I turned mine off, and no problem. So start looking there.

Comment: @Banana Woah, take it easy. I was just trying to point him in the right direction.

Comment: haha don't worry not mad at you @Christian! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Christian sorry  lol, i didnt mean to sound angry xD

Comment: _“dude you dont expect him to tell all his users to turn their javascript off do you?”_ – no, but maybe we expect him to know what the scripts _he_ is embedding are doing in the first place …?

Answer (score 0):

This is on the first line of clientResponse.js:

```
$("[type='password']").focus(function () {
    this.type = "text";
}).blur(function () {
    this.type = "password";
})
```

Remove it, and it should work like you want it to.

Yours is minified, but I beautified it for a cleaner look.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#requestTitle').blur(function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
            $(this).addClass("empty");
            $(this).animate({
                marginLeft: "15px"
            }, 200);
            $(this).animate({
                marginLeft: "0px"
            }, 200);
            return (false);
        }
        return (true);
    });
    $("#requestTitle").change(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("empty")) {
            $(this).removeClass("empty");
        }
    });
    $('#requestDesc').blur(function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
            $(this).addClass("empty");
            $(this).animate({
                marginLeft: "15px"
            }, 200);
            $(this).animate({
                marginLeft: "0px"
            }, 200);
            return (false);
        }
        return (true);
    });
    $("#requestDesc").change(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("empty")) {
            $(this).removeClass("empty");
        }
    });
    $('#timeFrame').blur(function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
            $(this).addClass("empty");
            $(this).animate({
                marginLeft: "15px"
            }, 200);
            $(this).animate({
                marginLeft: "0px"
            }, 200);
            return (false);
        }
        return (true);
    });
    $("#timeFrame").change(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("empty")) {
            $(this).removeClass("empty");
        }
    });
    $('.alertMsg .alert-close').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(this).css('diplay', 'none');
            });
        });
    });
    $('.tool-tip').hover(function () {
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        $('<p class="tooltip"></p>').text(title).appendTo('body').fadeIn(
            'slow');
    }, function () {
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
        $('.tooltip').remove();
    }).mousemove(function (e) {
        var mousey = e.pageY + 0;
        var mousex = e.pageX + -20;
        $('.tooltip').css({
            top: mousey,
            left: mousex
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: ok it will hide the password now. But when you have something inputted into the email address field. The problem occurs again.

Comment: I see, that must a problem elsewhere. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Hmm, I fail to see anything else wrong with the code, must be something with bootstrap (Custom build?) or jquery.